How to properly use xcode source control without all of its autogenerated project files?
I set up source control on a small project with Xcode, but I quickly found that there are a lot of random files and folders that Xcode makes for my project that are also getting picked up by git. Not sure if it is helpful to keep them to perfectly restore a previous commit, but it definitely makes it harder to view changed files when the list of changes after changing one file comes out to a length of 168. Is there any way that I can add all of these automatically to gitignore or at least hide them?
I was thinking to add certain files to gitignore, but there are far to many to manually do, and there are also entire folders, and the names seem like they will change each time I build the project. .

Are all of those files inside some other folder? Can you show us more of the structure please? I'd guess the answer is going to be to ignore the parent folder of all of those, since it looks like they're temporary build files. Did you start with a .gitignore generated by xcode, or did you get one from somewhere online? Where from? Or did you start with an empty gitignore?

@Rup It seems most of these files are in DerivedData or Build folder, but I am not sure if there is anything of use in these folders that I would still want to version control.

Agreed, I think you can probably exclude the whole folders. gitignore.io which is a gitignore generator excludes both of them if you choose swift,xcode
